# How do I load a file with 'loadtxt ?'

Tags: python, numpy

Sorry for this beginner question, but...I'm a Python beginner. Still, I can't seem to find a proper answer for loadtxt not 'finding my file'...

```
import os
print(os.getcwd())
```

returns, I suppose, my current working directory.

In this case:`C:\Users\danie\Desktop\python`

So, when I place my csv file in it and run:

```
import numpy as np
dataset=np.loadtxt('Desktop/python/pima-indians-diabetes.csv', delimiter=",")
```

I still get

> OSError: Desktop/python/pima-indians-diabetes.csv not found.

I have tried relative paths, absolute paths, `f=open(..)`, paths with '/' and paths with '\' or with '\'...but nothing seems to make it work..
Any ideas ?

**RESOLVED: I tried Max L's hint: print(os.listdir(os.getcwd()))
and I saw the list of files in my current directory:...'pima-indians-diabetes.csv.csv'   ....turns out I had put the csv extension on the file name myself **

Comment: Are you missing a ```/``` here: ```dataset=np.loadtxt('Desktop/python/pima-indians-diabetes.csv', delimiter=",")```. Also, if you're trying to open a file in the current working directory you don't need this part: ```Desktop/python/```. Just the file name.

Comment: Try the **full** absolute path to the file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your working directory is `C:\Users\danie\Desktop\python`, that means that is where Python will start to look for files to import when using a relative path.

What is a relative path? It's the path to the file you want, relative to your current working directory. If a file is in the same directory, no prefix should be needed so it should just be

```
np.loadtxt('pima-indians-diabetes.csv', ...
```

Comment: **Thank you for the response. Still, after doing so**: dataset=np.loadtxt('pima-indians-diabetes.csv', delimiter=",")    **I get**:..............................in open
    raise IOError("%s not found." % path)
OSError: pima-indians-diabetes.csv not found.
[Finished in 1.9s]

Comment: I'm wondering if the fact I installed Anaconda not so long ago made a difference as it may mess up with the file paths

Comment: I would try making sure that a command like `type C:\Users\danie\Desktop\python\pima-indians-diabetes.csv` runs in your command line and works. That would indicate that the file is in the right place and that this should work.

Another thing you could try is adding the line `print(os.listdir(os.getcwd()))` above the `np.loadtxt` call to print out all the files in the current working directory and see if you see your file.

Comment: I tried **print(os.listdir(os.getcwd()))** and I got as a result ['cross_validation.py', 'learn numpy.py', **'pima-indians-diabetes.csv.csv'**, 'xgboost_learn.py'] .....**so my filename was wrong. Thank you for that !**